# Importing user and order history from custom ecommerce store to magento

Tags: database, magento, migration

We have been using ecommerce script for our site that we bought from ecommercetemplates.com for a few years.

Now we are migrating to magento. Sites are set up and ready but we need to import all users or the old site to magento along with their order history.

Can anyone suggest any good and easy way doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We moved from oscommerce to magento a few years ago and used an extension to do this as the default magento customer import was a nightmare to format the import files for.

If you can get your customer records into flat records in a spreadsheet (we always use OpenOffice Calc for these jobs) save as a utf8 .csv and you'll can then look at an extension.

Have a look at [this extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-advanced-customer-import-export.html) it should be a good place to start - we have used the product importer without any issues.

Comment: Any Idea about how I can import order history of customer too.